# Git submodules workflow when modifying third party code

Tags: git, git-submodules

So I have a project A with a third party dependency B which lives on some other server.

If I add B as a submodule of A, then I can easily get the third party changes to B using the standard submodule workflow. Furthermore, I can clone A to another machine and have B in the exact state that I'd expect.

If I add B as a submodule of A and make my own set of changes and commits to B, I can still get third party updates to B. However, if I try to clone A to another machine, B will end up in a bad state since the commits I made to B aren't 'public'.

What's a good workflow to accomplish this second scenario? Namely, being able to use, modify, and update third party submodules from a repository without sacrificing the distributed nature of git?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fork `B`. Include your fork as a submodule of `A`. Pulling upstream changes is then a two step process; pull the change from `B` into your fork, update your submodule in `A`.

This also assumes that your fork repository will be accessible to whatever other machine you want to checkout `A` on.